# tableview is crashing on clicking on cell or on scrolling in ios 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios5

I made a demo empty app and add a navigation controller with the view

```
UINavigationController *navBar = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:objFirstViewControllerViewController];
[self.window addSubview:navBar.view];
```

After it i add a table view on the first view controller like this .

```
UITableView* demotableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
demotableView.delegate = self;
demotableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:demotableView];
```

and the delegate function of the table view and main cell for row function like this way

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello this is sample text";
cell.textLabel.minimumFontSize = 12;
cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE;
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Copperplate" size:18];
return cell;
}
```

But when i scroll on my table or click any cell to go on the next view it just crash and give these two error on clicking and scrolling respectively.

```
[__NSCFArray tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]
[__NSCFDictionary tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]
```

I don't understand what is getting wrong this code it have been working with the prior os properly

Any body can help please ?

Here is the code for did select row

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
Second *anotherViewController = [[Second alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];

}
```

and no of row is this one

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 15;
}
```

Comment: can you add code of didselectrow and numberofrows methods as well?

Comment: @RIP i have added the code please check

Comment: Your errors suggest that tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: are being sent to an NSArray and/or NSDictionary.  Are you sure you are passing an object that implements the UITableViewDataSourceDelegate protocol as the demotableView.dataSource?

Comment: actually i just use this demotableView.delegate = self;
demotableView.dataSource = self; and in .h i declared that i want to use the delegate and datasource method of the table view beside this i don't paas any thing to cells

Comment: @Ballu seems like something related to release of some variable, can you please double check on release statements that you had written in your code.

Comment: @RIP i checked but in the code i haven't use the release statement any where instead i am using the ARC with ios 5.1 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I misused the ARC what are the changes I made to make the app run successfully actually it was crashing due to memory leak I reference the class in delegate with local object but the it got released when it tried to add the data on it and when table's delegate and datasource try to add the things in the current class it was released and it throw message from those message instances, I was stuck because I was thinking it is happening due to me having taken an empty kind of application but after adding the lines below in the delegate class I got the problem solved.

What I did in the delegate class in the `.h` file:

```
 FirstViewControllerViewController *objFirstViewControllerViewController;

@property (strong, nonatomic)  FirstViewControllerViewController *objFirstViewControllerViewController;
```

Then my table started behaving properly and all things that I was having problem in.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code by this and try:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if(cell == nil)
  {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  }
  cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello this is sample text";

  cell.textLabel.minimumFontSize = 12;

  cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE;

  cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Copperplate" size:18];

  return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it is still having the same issue on scrolling and clicking i checked after replacing the code no effect on the problems

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set `demotableView.delegate = self;` 
you have to implement the `tabelView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` function which solves the crash on selecting(on Click) a Cell.

To resolve the crash of scrolling, you hav to implement

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

method.

P.S: In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:, all the lines except `cell.textLabel.text` should be inside

```
if(cell == nil){
}
```

and please follow proper maemory management rules

Comment: no it is still having the issue i have done what you asking for to do i write the code for noofrowsinsection and also write the code for did select row and also i put the lines in the if (cell == nil){} but it is having the problem .. I am making the empty application from the project start is that could be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please try this....

add your table view like this..

```
 productList = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,102, 320, 267) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
 productList.delegate = self;
 productList.dataSource = self;
 productList.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 [self.view addSubview:productList];
```

and add these methods....

```
  #pragma mark Table view data source

  // Customize the number of sections in the table view.
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
      return 1;
   }


 // Customize the number of rows in the table view.
   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return (your row count);
    }


 // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
     }

 // Configure the cell.

         cell.textLabel.text = @"Title";
         cell.detailTextLabel.text = formattedString;
         cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

         return cell;

      }

  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      Second *anotherViewController = [[Second alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];

   }
```

Comment: Thanks Ansul but i tried it too it still having the same problem ... :(

Comment: ok.. Just do one thing , put break point in didselectrowatindexpath method and check...

Comment: I put the break point but strange thing come to me it never goes in the delegate and datasource functions of the table view and got crashing

Comment: it seems it got memory leak in the cell for row at indexpath function .. i think so

Comment: just tell me you add navigation controller and table view in same controller or different????  because if your navigation working properly then its also working for table view of if not then first check your navigation controller

Comment: i added navigation controller with a viewcontroller and then added the viewcontroler on it and then table view on the view.